# Android Floating Action Button wrong position despite gravity is set

Tags: android, android-framelayout, floating-action-button, layout-gravity

I'm currently facing two different issues, both regarding fab gravity behavior.

In my layout I have a section consisting in a `FrameLayout` with an `ImageView` and a `FloatingActionButton` as children views.

```
`<RelativeLayout ...>

    *Here's a toolbar*

    <ScrollView ...>

        <LinearLayout ...>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/prof_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_editing_pic"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_editing_pic"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_profilo_utente"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/floating_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:tint="@color/dark_gray"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_image"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end|right"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccentEasy"
                    app:fabSize="mini"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            *Other sections*

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

---

- Issue 1: Android version >= Lollipop

The FAB is right where it should be but you can see that its shadow is clearly cut without the supposed fading.

[image: Post-Lollipop behavior]

---

- Issue 2: Android version < Lollipop

The FAB is not where it's supposed to be.

[image: Pre-Lollipop behavior]

---

I tried anything that came to my mind and that I found online and here on SO.
I understand that it has to do with the different padding management that the core code does if the OS is pre or post Lollipop, and with the attribute `useCompatPadding` (which I tried in different combinations), but I can't figure out how to successfully resolve it.

---

### UPDATE

Thanks to the suggestion I managed to solve Issue #1.

As far as Issue #2 is concerned, though, I still can't solve it.
In my new fabStyle-v21 a `layout_margins` of 5dp since it perfectly suited my needs.
I then tried putting a 0dp margin in the default style, but still nothing, even trying negative margins.

Comment: Fab are usually inside CoordinatorLayout, have you rrplace your root layout for it?

Comment: Yes, I have, but the behavior was the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1-** If you want to see the `elevation`(shadow) of Views like `FAB, Button` etc. you must leave space around them. For example, you can set margins. Using padding to the parent Layout of `FAB`, will not work if there is no space between `FAB` and edges of parent Layout

**Issue 2-** Floating Action Button has different margin and padding values  before Lollipop devices. You can use different styles.xml files for different api levels.

styles.xml for different folders:

**values-v21**

```
<style name="fabStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">16dp</item>
</style>
```

**values** (default)

```
<style name="fabStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
</style>
```

**usage:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/fabStyle"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    app:elevation="6dp"/>
```

**UPDATE:** try adding `app:useCompatPadding="true"` to your FAB without changing other arrangements.

Comment: @MassimoBaldrighi Updated my answer too.

Comment: I had already tried that. This attribute will only make the v21 layouts behave like below 21.